# Keeping a loaded View part of the tabController when the tableView cell is clicked?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uistoryboard

I have a tabbed application with a TableView in the FirstView. I want to be able click on a cell in the TableView and load a new view.

Right now, when the cell is clicked I go to the view I want but it isn't part of the tab bar controller (as in I I don't see the two tabs on the bottom) and I also can't get back to the FirstView where the TableView is located.

I have seen tutorials on this but they are all starting from scratch. I already have a lot of content on my FirstView so I don't want to start over.

I think I have to put in a Navigation Controller but I don't know how to do that without starting over and I also don't know where I would put it.

Here is the StoryBoard for my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrCt5.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you are trying to do but try to control click from your cell in the Home Table View Controller to your Friend View Controller, this will create a segue from the cell to the view controller so the view controller will be called once the cell is clicked.

Please let me know if this is what you are going for!

Comment: I have a function for the cell to go to the friend View when clicked but my problem is the tab bar on the bottom disappears and I don't have a way to get back to the HomeController

Comment: That is because the tableview is pushing the friends view on top of it and you need to press back on the top left to unwind it, if you add a bar in the friends view and drag a segue to the view you will probably create a memory leak, it can be done but it will require to be done in code instead in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is select your table view controller, go to the `Editor` menu, and choose "Embed in Navigation Controller". This will insert a navigation controller between the tab bar controller and your table view controller. Now when you select a cell, you should use a "show" segue to go (via a push) to your new view controller.